# Struggling with View Slider Image Rotation

Tags: views, 7, javascript

I'm struggling to let the images rotate with the View Slider module.

When I add an image of content type of say -> image_slider. At the moment it only replaces the current slider image with the latest published content of type image_slider instead of rotating between the images.

Where can I set/change this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I added 2 images to one node and now when I think it wants to rotate between the images I get this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic setup for the slider depends on two factors:

1.) A collections of nodes of a particular type, in your case image_slider.

2.) A view that manages the slideshow outputting it as either as a page, block or both.

So, initially go to create (for example) 3 nodes, each containing an image, as the content-type image_slider.

Then go ahead and access your view under admin/structure/views and ensure that:

- The format (under Format) is set to Slideshow
- You are "showing" (Show:) Fields (under Format)
- That you have selected your image field to be called (under Fields).
- That your filter criteria has the content type set to image_slider
- **Finally, that under "Pager" (in the second column) you have set the pager to display "All Items" - you can change this later to limit the output but for now this will ensure that all node-fields, which meet the previously mentioned conditions, will be output.**

Once all of these conditions are met, save the view and it should already display the slider in action at the bottom of the page as part of the preview. If everything went smooth, you can now access either your view-page output or set the block under blocks to display your slideshow throughout your website.